# select some values of a row in a matrix

Tags: r

In R with a matrix:

```
m <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 4) 
colnames(m) <- letters[1:4]
```

In the case I want to select just one value, it works. Like this,

```
subset(m, m[,4] == 17)
```

But if I want for example 3 values, I get an error. look at this:

```
subset(m, m[,4] == c(17,19,20,"|"))
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without using subset

```
m[ m[,4] %in% c(17, 19, 20),]
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `==` by `%in%`

```
subset(m, m[,4] %in% c(17,19,20))
```