# How to get a subset of a list?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [select some values of a row in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529625/select-some-values-of-a-row-in-a-matrix)
>   [R subset a data frame with multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465996/r-subset-a-data-frame-with-multiple-keys)

Say I have a list

> > test

```
  V1    V2   V3
1  1   one  uno
2  2   two duos
3  3 three tres
4  4 four cuatro
```

and a vector `a<-c("one","three")`.

I want to get the subset of the list `test` where the element of the second column are from vector `a`.

So in this case answer should be something like,

```
  V1    V2   V3
1  1   one  uno
2  3 three tres
```

I want something on the lines of
`test[test[,2]=="one",]` but for multiple values. How to do that?

Comment: ah. `test[test[,2] %in% a,]` works. Any other way? I thought there should be some way to use the `apply` functions?

Comment: OK. just asking which was the preferred way of doing it. %in% works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a FAQ for this? There should be one since this is asked frequently.

Comment: @Roland, I didn't see one in the r-faq tag, but maybe check in the chat room? Might also be possible to merge some of the related questions, but I don't know how that's done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is `%in%` (although you could also use `match` and `subset`). See below.

```
df <- data.frame(V1=1:4, V2=c("one", "two", "three", "four"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
fil <- c("one", "three")

> df
#   V1    V2
# 1  1   one
# 2  2   two
# 3  3 three
# 4  4  four

> fil
# [1] "one"   "three"

# subset df by column V2 using fil

# using %in%
df[df$V2 %in% fil, ]

# using subset
subset(df, V2 %in% fil)

# using match
df[!is.na(match(df$V2, fil)), ] # (or) 
df[which(!is.na(match(df$V2, fil))), ]

# all gives
#   V1    V2
# 1  1   one
# 3  3 three
```